# What are the benefits finding the inverse of a matrix using the "adjoint" method over RREF?

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

Good morning!

I am studying for a linear algebra test, where I know in advance that I will have to solve a system of equations (Ax = b) using Cramer's Rule and by also by multiplying A inverse with b.

Is there any situation in which it would be better to use the adjoint method to find the inverse?

I don't expect an answer before the test, but I got curious during my studies about the various applications of these rules.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's a matter of personal preference. I would have to say the row reduction method is easier, since the other method involves computing the determinant as well as the adjoint matrix, which can be difficult. I would say the adjoint is useful for $3\times 3$ matrices and lower, but $4\times 4$ and higher it becomes tedious and more mistakes can happen.

Comment: @Dave Thanks. That was my suspicion, as we were told to use our preference on the test. It just left me wondering why we were taught the Adjoint method when it seems more tedious in ever situation that I can conceive of.

Comment: In matrix algebra, you are not always interested in the actual numerical solution, but just in an answer where a vector $x$ is expressed as a product of matrices. e.g. $x=A^{-1}b$ would then be a possible final answer. This is useful in proof writing.